# What's the best modifier for guns?

Tags: terraria-console

S.D.M.G is a Moonlord drop, and I want to reforge it to the best modifier, but don't know what the best one is.

Answer (score 0):

**Unreal** usually provides the best option for any ranged weapon; you can check on the wiki to see what the best modifier is for the specific example you're using. For example, the [S.D.M.G.](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/S.D.M.G.) page has it just before the contents.

There's also the [best modifiers](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Modifiers#Best_modifiers) page, which is helpful to learn if you don't want to keep checking the wiki:

**Godly** - Any non-overhead melees excluding shortswords/Terrarian
**Legendary** - All other Melee weapons, including Whips
**Demonic** - Ranged/Magic weapons with no knockback
**Unreal** - All other Ranged weapons
**Mythical** - All other magic weapons
**Ruthless** - All other summon weapons
**Light** - All tools

Comment: It may be in your best interest to post some of the text from that best modifiers page. If that page ceases to exist, your answer becomes useless, so we typically frown upon link only answers.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf The question asked specifically for guns, which I have provided at the very start of the answer. I will edit to adjust for all of the best modifiers, though.